# How to read Data form External GPS Accessory, like Dual XGPS 160 External GPS in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gps

How to read Data `like Battery status, GPS Location Satellite Position etc`, of Dual XGPS 160 External GPS Accessory in iOS just like Dual Status Tool App in Apple Store.

I have used **ExternalAccessory**`.Framework` which is used only for its connectivity check.

How can I read its logged data?

Answer (score 0):

Most of GPS devices with BT connectivity can be connected with BT Serial Port profile, what I suppose you have already done. Usually, those devices are sending NMEA protocol messages with some frequency. You just need to parse this strings and extract required data.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183

For information about extra features like saved tracks etc. you should check device / device chipset documentation.